# Angular 2 upgrade from RC4 to RC7

Tags: angular

I'm trying to upgrade an app from RC4 to RC7 and I have created an app.module.ts in my src/app folder.

my main.ts in my `src` folder has the following line:

```
import { AppModule } from './app/';
```

Which returns the following error:

```
WARNING in ./src/main.ts
9:41 export 'AppModule' was not found in './app/'

ERROR in [default] c:\xampp\htdocs\newPROJECT\src\main.ts:6:9
Module '"c:/xampp/htdocs/newPROJECT/src/app/index"' has no exported member 'AppModule'.
```

Why I get this error? I did the same as another project which works..

my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpModule,RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { routing,
         appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';

//Routes
import { ComboFinderComponent }    from './combo-finder/combo-finder.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ComboFinderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
  ],
  providers: [
  {provide:RequestOptions, useClass: CustomRequestOptions }
  ],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create `index.ts` in `app` folder to export `AppModule` :

//index.ts

```
export * from './app.module';
```

Or you can import `AppModule` in your `main.ts` as follows  :

```
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
```